# does encapsulation requires more processing than public variable

Tags: c#, c++, class, encapsulation

I'm used to using encapsulation no matter what, all of my variables are private.
But when I'm handling thousands of instances with thousands of properties, I start thinking about optimization, wondering if the benefits of encapsulation justify the performance penalty (if any)

I'm aware of why one should use encapsulation but what I'm asking about is: **Is encapsulation worth the processing it requires if it's not required to be used ? How much does it use ?**

Comment: Only micro-optimize when you absolutely need to.  Unless you're actually _observing_ and able to _measure_ performance problems that need to be addressed, prefer more flexible and easily supportable code.

Comment: **In todays age of computing power, encapsulation does not cost you any processing power, none whatsoever.** And by none whatsoever, I mean that you will not lose enough to be noticeable. There are so many optimization levels inbetween you and your data access (the compiler, the VM, the OS...), that any OS multitasking hiccup will be more noticeable than your encapsulation.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing the point of encapsulation. The point of encapsulation is that the object controls ALL interaction with it's fields. Thus enforcing business logic uniformly and protecting the state of the system. Given that you would have to run the business logic anyway... you're not saving anything by just using data objects.

Comment: that's what i actually mentioned above, i've mentioned that i may not always need encapsulation so should i use it anyway or it would be a waste of processing? how much processing it uses? got my point ?

Comment: @AndrewxXx if you don't need encapsulation then you have an anemic system and are probably mixing logic in dangerous and untestable ways

Comment: @AndrewxXx read David's comment. Unless you've profiled that this is a problem, you shouldn't even care.

Comment: If you know that a variable being changed directly would never cause undefined behaviour, then it is okay to make that variable public. A position vector, or example, might be an example of a public variable.  Or maybe a colour.

Comment: i never said i don't need encapsulation in general, just in certain cases where i the only one who will be using those vars and got more checks on events itself and not on the assignment, why this is going off topic :\

Answer (score 1):

Your first choice should be to encapsulate things. Most of the time, the setter and getter functions should get inlined.

All you "lose" is the time it takes for any extra logic involved in the actual verification that you are not setting an invalid value, etc. But you don't want to miss that out just for the sake of speed, would you?

So, if the alternative is to write

```
if (x >= 0) obj.x = x;
```

or 
    obj.setx(x);     // where setx checks that x >= 0.

which is better?

If there are performance criteria for the system, then benchmark. If you are meeting the criteria, fine. If not, figure out where the bottlenecks are. But unless your setter and getter functions are "normal" ones (that is, just storing the value after some checking), it shouldn't be the bottlenecks. Typical bottlenecks are "poor choice of algorithms".